# Playing around with ${\int\frac{dx}{x^2-2x}}$

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, indefinite-integrals

Found the above integral in the old posts and figured I would play around with it using double substitution and integration of partial derivatives. So here goes.

$$\int \frac {dx}{x^2-2x}$$

$$= \int\frac {dx}{x(x-2)}$$

Then let

${u=x,du=dx}$

and

${v=x-2,dv=dx}$

Now here is where I stumble on to something or show a lack of competence so you be the judge. If you judge it the later please tell me what I am doing wrong.

$$={\int\int u^{-1}v^{-1}\delta u \delta v}$$
$$=\frac {ln|u|}{v}\frac{ln|v|}{u}$$
substituting back I get
$$= \frac {ln|x|}{x-2} \frac {ln|x-2|}{x}+c$$

Did I get this right?? or do I need to go back to the drawing board?

note:
I know there are other ways to do this but please critique this approach. Thank you

${EDIT}$

The above math was incorrect. Because ${dy=udv+vdu}$ I left the post unedited to so others may follow the conversation. The math should read:

$${\frac {dx}{f(x)g(x)}}$$

let

${u=f(x), \delta u=g(x)\delta x=v\delta x, then:\delta u/v= \delta x}$

${v=g(x),\delta v=f(x)\delta x=u\delta x, then:\delta v/u=\delta x}$

This only makes sense as partials so

${dx=\delta x_1+\delta x_2}$

then

${dx=\delta u/v+\delta v/u}$

That makes the expression
$${\frac{1}{uv}(\delta u/v+\delta v/u) }$$ Distributing $${\frac {1}{uv^2} \delta u + \frac {1}{vu^2} \delta  v } $$

then $${\int \frac {dx}{f(x)g(x)}= \int \frac{1}{uv} = \int\frac {1}{uv^2} \delta u + \int \frac {1}{vu^2} \delta  v = \frac {lnu}{v^2}+ \frac {lnv}{u^2}+c}$$

Then the original expression $${\int \frac{1}{x(x-2)}={\frac {ln|x|}{(x-2)^2 } + \frac {ln|x-2|}{x^2}+c}}$$

Went back over the algorthim and it looks right. So I am pretty sure this is the answer.

${Edit}$

Never mind this method just won't work.

Comment: x is not two different things. "u" and "v" are two different functions of x.

Comment: If you differentiate this quantity, do you get the old integrand back?  Thanks to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this is the ultimate test.

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work.  It would be great to be able to integrate a product by using different substitutions on the two factors.

Comment: There is only one $dx$ term in the given integral. But are you "replacing" that with both $du$ and $dv$? That can't be right?

Comment: @ imranfat Yeah that's what I think too. The problem is that I treated the partial derivatives the same. So du does not equal dx nor does dv because they are derivatives with respect to the other function. Let me try this again ( just because I like beating dead horses) and repost as an answer.

Comment: @imranfat  Yep That was the problem. I redid the math and posted in the edit.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Chris Do you know how to formally justify all those substitutions you wrote in the question?

Comment: @dani_s sorry just reread your post... Formally? How do you mean? The work is posted in the edit  is this not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try using partial fraction decomposition?

$$\int \frac{dx}{x(x-2)} = \int \Big(\dfrac A{x} + \frac B{x-2}\Big) \,dx$$

$$A(x-2) + Bx = 1 \implies -2A = 1, \quad A = - B$$

$$A = -\frac 12, B = \frac 12$$

---

$$\begin{align} \int \frac{dx}{x(x-2)} & = \frac 12 \int \Big(\dfrac{1}{x - 2} - \frac 1x\Big) \,dx \\ \\ & = \dfrac 12 \left( \ln|x - 2| - \ln |x|\right) + C \\ \\ & = \frac 12 \ln\left|\frac{x-2}{x}\right|+C\end{align}$$

Comment: Short answer is I wanted to do it this way. So I did. I want to know if this approach works and if I did it right. If I got it right Great... If I got it wrong.... well that's why I joined SE...to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now I understand that way to do it. But like I said, I enjoy beating dead horses...se edit

Comment: Funny how many people say I should go this way. I could just as easily Use Trig substitution by completing the square on the denominator. Likewise I can chose to do it this way but I'd rather see if I can make my way work. I appreciate this answer but kindly be rude and shread the OP instead.